# hot restart with torquebox-lite?

Tags: torquebox

Is hot restarting possible with the torquebox-lite gem? I don't see anything about it on the github page but I'd be surprised if it wasn't possible, can anybody tell me how to do it or if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot deployment (redeploying without restarting the server)

```
touch $APP_ROOT/torquebox-lite/deployments/<app_name>-knob.yml.dodeploy
```

The app_name is usually the name of the application's directory

https://github.com/torquebox/torquebox-lite